# C#: creating a parent list class of children objects

Tags: c#, list, object, ienumerable

I'm beginning with C# code...

I would like to create a class called "VolumeList" which is a list of "Volume" objects.

So something like this:

```
public class Volume
{
    private string name;

    public Volume(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public static List<Volume> VolumeList { get; set; } = new List<Volume>();
}
```

But when I do that, I can't directly access `VolumeList`. I have to call it with `Volume.VolumeList`... (which is not logical...) I would like something like that:

```
VolumeList.Current.Name (it should return the name of the current volume)

VolumeList.Last.Name (it should return the name of the last volume of the list)

VolumeList.Add = ... (it adds a new volume to the VolumeList)
```

So I also want the `IEnumerable` properties (I think it is this name..).

Please can you help me to create the correct class hierarchy, and to show me how to access my Volume Objects stored in the VolumeList with the listed ("Current", Last,...) properties?

For example, if I load my VolumeList in a Combobox, and I select a Volume, this one get the "Current" property all the time in my application.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In basic OOP, static methods or properties cannot be accessed by an instance of a class. They are created at compile time. We have to access them as if we are accessing a constant variable using the class name as a namespace illusion. What you need to is remove the static declaration and do this. Also you do not need the this keyword. C# is smart to know what you are trying to access

```
public class Volume {
    private string _name;

    public Volume(string name) {
        _name = name;
    }
    
    public string Name {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
   
    public List<Volume> VolumeList = new List<Volume>();

}
```

You can then use LINQ to manipulate the items in the volume list. Use [LINQ TUTORIAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) to learn how LINQ works.

**USAGE**

```
Volume vol = new Volume("First Volume Object");
vol.VolumeList.Add(new Volume("First Sub Volume"));
vol.VolumeList.Add(new Volume("Second Sub Volume"));
        
Console.WriteLine(vol.VolumeList.First().Name);
Console.WriteLine(vol.VolumeList.Last().Name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will build my VolumeList like that. Can you show me the way to manipulate the items with LINQ? I need also the "Current" property for my VolumeList. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you give me an upvote for my answer first?

Comment: How do you mean by the word FIRST